# Android development : Listview with android:onclick attribute on item

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick

I'm beginner in android development and i a have question about Listview and android:onclick attribute.
I try to use attribute android:onclick ="myMethod" on each element of my listview instead of define OnItemClickListener/onItemClick (too much verbose for me)

MyMethod is executed but how can i get clicked element (current context) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: not clear post your code and some more info or problem

Comment: Please post the way your adapter works.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, setting an `OnItemClickListener` might seem a bit scary, but it's really not a big deal at all (and a core concept you should be learning anyway!).

So if you have a simple layout with a ListView in it like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can set up an `OnItemClickListener` with just this code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_listview_layout);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListview);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Every time an item is clicked, you can handle it right here.
            }
        });
    }
```

So every time an item in your list is clicked, the `onItemClick` method is fired, and you can figure out which item was clicked by using the `int position` argument that comes in.

Answer (score 0):

If i am right your question is about implementing on click listener on each listrow item instead of list row.

If that is correct this is how you should implement:

1.In your adapter of `getView()` method you might be inflating a layout for list row like below:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, parent, false);


        return convertView;
    }
```

In the above code list_row_layout is the xml file i'm inflating.

Go to that layout and add the following line `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root level of the xml layout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"<!--This is the line i'm talking about-->
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/review_main_user_image_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/review_main_user_image"
            android:background="@drawable/reviews_x_trail_user_image_border"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_help_user" />
        <TextView
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Me"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/review_main_user_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/review_main_user_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/review_main_user_image_layout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/review_main_user_image_layout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/review_main_title"
            android:text="Good Product For The Price"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/review_main_rating"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/apptheme_ratingbar_small_holo_light"
                android:numStars="5"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="12-Jun-1993"
                android:id="@+id/review_main_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That't it now in your adapter getView method you can implement on click listener for each widget you have in that layout.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ReviewsXTrailViewHolder reviewsXTrailViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_review_main, parent, false);
            TextView title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.review_main_user_image);

            //title.setOnclickListener()

        return convertView;
    }
```

In that above code i have added on click listener for textview.I hope it will work

Comment below if that doesn't work